# Strange error when using CSS boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I imported a bootstrap CSS file, but I'm getting a weird error from it:

> None of the "sha384" hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.

I import the file with this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, your hash is wrong.

Comment: thanks, I solve it, wrong href, like you said

Comment: I think the integrity you have used is associated with the minified stylesheet of bootstrap. Changing you bootstrap source to bootstrap.min.css should get rid of that error for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add the wrong link, here is the good one, notice its got the  **min**.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/ to find the current one.